# CheckBox Text distances from Checkbox

Tags: html, css, reactjs

How Do I make the text be together with checkbox? Kinds of distances themselves from the Checkbox.

[image: 1222222-er.png]

**My code:**

```css
.checkboxInput {
  margin: auto;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 23px;
  font-family: 'Gill Sans', 'Gill Sans MT', Calibri, 'Trebuchet MS', sans-serif;
}

.checkboxInput:after {
  display: flex;
  margin-left: 240px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<div className="TandCAgreements">
  <input type="checkbox" className="checkboxInput" />You Confirm that you have read and agreed to the Subscription and Cancellation Terms and you acknowledge that your information will be used accordance to our Privacy and Cookie Policy
  <input type="checkbox" className="checkboxInput" />You Confirm that you have read and agreed to the Subscription and Cancellation Terms and you acknowledge that your information will be used accordance to our Privacy and Cookie Policy
  <input type="checkbox" className="checkboxInput" />You Confirm that you have read and agreed to the Subscription and Cancellation Terms and you acknowledge that your information will be used accordance to our Privacy and Cookie Policy
</div>
```

**Edit**

Please this is what it looks like now

[image: new112.png]

Wanted it to be at the starting margin of the textfield.

Comment: Have you tried to remove 

 margin-left: 240px;

Comment: did just now and its still the same thing.

Comment: remove `width: 50%` ...on `.checkboxInput`

Comment: @Sayog. Pls see what it looks like now. Please see Edits. I had wanted it to be at the starting point of the input text. Like the same Margin

Comment: Please see edit.

Comment: why don't you use '<li>' tag?

Comment: @mkafiyan how do I use that to wordwrap those checkbox Labels

Comment: wrap checkbox and text with <p> tag. <p class="checkboxInput"><input type="checkbox" />
            You Confirm that you have read and agreed to the Subscription and Cancellation Terms and you acknowledge that your information will be used accordance to our Privacy and Cookie Policy</p>

Comment: @Evans check this jsfiddle I made. I think it is what you want!
: https://jsfiddle.net/r975zfkn/1/